# Setting currentTime to anything sets time back to 0 in videojs

Tags: video.js

I'm doing something fairly simple with videojs. I simply want to set the time to an arbitrary point on the timeline by clicking on an externally build UI (not the default seek stuff, but a set of divs that are acting like a progress bar.)

All the documentation and every post seems to indicate that setting currentTime as in object.currentTime(time) works. But in my case it doesn't. Not in the console, not anywhere.

Here's my code:

```
function clearSetTimeBug(videoObj,timeToSetTo){     
    console.log('timeToSetTo:'+timeToSetTo);
    console.log("-1."+videoObj.id()+" readyState(): "+videoObj.readyState());//returns 4 (loaded)
    console.log("0."+videoObj.id()+" bufferedEnd(): "+videoObj.bufferedEnd());//returns about 2 seconds ahead of where the playhead is)
    if(videoObj.bufferedEnd()>timeToSetTo){
        console.log("1."+videoObj.id()+" currentTime(): "+videoObj.currentTime()); // returns a valid videojs object id and then shows the currentTime to be where the video's current timecode as a float.
        videoObj.currentTime(timeToSetTo);//this should totally work!
        console.log("2."+videoObj.id()+" currentTime(): "+videoObj.currentTime());// shows that the current time is 0!
    }else{ 
        //I added this to just go to as far as it's buffered, but this doesn't work either
        console.log("3."+videoObj.id()+" currentTime(): "+videoObj.currentTime());
        console.log("4. newTime: "+videoObj.bufferedEnd());
        videoObj.currentTime(videoObj.bufferedEnd());
        pageTime=videoObj.bufferedEnd();
        console.log("5."+videoObj.id()+": "+videoObj.currentTime());// still shows that the current time is 0!
        console.log("6. pageTime:"+pageTime);
    }
}
```

The player is spun up like this:

```
function setUpPlayers(playerId,playlist,local_file,index){
    let myAspectRatio=heightRatio+":1"
    
    let videoTag="";
    videoTag +="<video id='playerInstance"+index+"' class='video-js vjs-fluid' width='100%' height='100%'>\n";
    videoTag +="\t<source src='"+playlist+"' type='video/mp4'>\n";
    videoTag +="</video>\n"
    $('#player'+index).html(videoTag);
    window["vjPlayer"+index]=videojs("playerInstance"+index, {"autoplay": false, "preload": "auto" });
}
```

Play() and pause() and even currentTime() to get the current time works. But trying to set it just forces the player to go back to 0.

I'm working in a Mac in Chrome Version 86.0.4240.80 and Firefox Developer's Edition 71.0b1 (64-bit). These are all local files and I'm running it from http://localhost:8000/index.php.

Comment: Wow...pretty funky coding, but you don't show us any actual log file values/output. Please post that.

Comment: Oh sure. Here's an example: https://jovijuan.com/images/crazy-currentTime.png

Comment: ![console shot](https://jovijuan.com/images/crazy-currentTime.png).

Answer (score 1):

In the video.js github channel, I figured out the answer to this question. I hadn't checked it on my server, so running the page locally screwed up the ability to click around and set currentTime. Quite strange, actually. I'm still not sure why it happens. You can see the comment here: https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/6900

Not the smartest move on my part, but hopefully this might help someone else in the future.